# How to extract log line from a json property with fluent bit

Tags: kubernetes, fluent-bit

My log messages look like this. What do I need to configure in fluentbit to extract the log line from the "log" property?

```
{
    "log": "{\"timestamp\":\"2022-09-30T20:01:50.002\",\"level\":\"INFO\",\"thread\":\"main\",\"logger\":\"com.app.Main\",\"message\":\"Started Main in 5.456 seconds (JVM running for 6.12)\",\"context\":\"default\"}\n",
    "stream": "stdout",
    "time": "2022-09-30T20:01:50.002746176Z"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing to change is to add the line below to parser.conf
parser.conf

```
Decode_Field json log
```

This leaves log in place but unencodes the content, so it is proper json.

Then in my case I had to use a modify filter to rename log to event for pushing to splunk.

For other cases you can use Decode_Field_As to also pull up the contents of log to top level.